# what is the limitation of concurrent users of an Access Point

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-access-point

I've been told that my purchased AP can support up to 30 concurrent users only in 802.11bgn protocol.

What is the limitation on the concurrent users supported, is it CPU speed of the board or bandwidth of the wireless module?

Answer (score 1):

If you can give a model I can be more specific.

It will be down to bandwidth.

Lets say for example you are using 802.11n. This has a speed of 450Megabits/ps. Lets divide that between 30 people. Each user has 15 Megabits/ps to work with, that's just over 2 megabytes per person.

We need to add our overheads, the amount of bandwidth used to encrypt the connection, the amount used by the AP/Computers to keep connection, the amount windows uses itself. Once you boil it down, there's only a little bit available per user.

At my place of work we use access points which are touted at 100 people per AP. That's partially because of it using 2.4 and 5ghz, so users are spread across the two frequencies. The Ap uses an array of directional antennas and chooses the best for the target device. This along with the management software reduces packet loss which means less retransmissions.

Comment: Thanks. I couldn't tell the model here as it is still in developing project. I have 2 APs'.  The AP now has a speed of 300Mbps (running 802.11bgn) and it could support 30 users (each transmitting TCP 384-768 kbps).  Second AP now has a speed of 1.3Gbps (running 802.11ac), however it is only able to support 15 people. Each users are streaming 2Mbps of video. Is this reasonable?

Comment: We can do the quick math. You have 1300 megabits, 1300/15= 86.6. You have 86 megabits per person, or 10.8 megabytes. Thats quite alot and I would have expected to fit in more people. There may be secondary considerations such as processing power, antennas etc. That play a part here. Best to clarify with the manufactuerer, I can only make conjecture and give you a best guestimate.